# AJAX Transition Effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get this transition effect working with AJAX but the effect doesn't work with it. I essentially have a wrapper class and an innerwrap class in each of my html pages. When you click one of the `navbar` items, the `innerwrap` in the current page fades out and the `innerwrap` in the clicked `navbar` link fades in. Here is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#navbar a').click(function () {
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $('.wrapper').fadeOut('.innewrap').load.fadeIn(url + ' .innerwrap');
        return false;
    });
});
```

The way I'm seeing it is that the current `innerwrap` fades out and the `innerwrap` of the clicked url fades in. I've been struggling with finding a solution through different questions here but I can't seem to find one that's similar to the way I have the code presented. If you can't help but can guide me towards a question where the code is kind of similar that would be awesome. Thank you!

Comment: start by checking your browser console for errors. Will be a very noticeable one for using `load` incorrectly. Then when you see that, you can go to the docs to see how it should be used

Comment: it seems like you're misusing (or not using) callbacks to your advantage. check out the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com) for where and how to put in callback functions.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm wrong, but what you do in your code is fading in something like `http://example.com/ .innerwrap` and that's because you are using `url` variable where you put value of `href` attribute from `a` element.

Try using `.load(url, function(){})` to achieve what you want. [HERE](http://api.jquery.com/load/) you'll find more about load() from jQuery ;) Also your `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` syntax seem to be a little strange.

I think this is more what you want:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#navbar a').click(function () {
        var aObj = $(this);
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $('.wrapper').load(url, function(){
            $(this).find('.innerwrap').fadeOut();
            $(a).find('.innerwrap').fadeIn();
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

I haven't tested this code.